# open a file with my script from GUI

Tags: 18.04, scripts, nautilus

I want to open a file with a script that I wrote myself, but when I right-click on the file, and select "Open With Other Application", I am given no option to run my own script, even though I know its path. I tried to press on the lens icon and paste the path, it does not work.

I do not want to start my script from the command line because the file is an image, one of 20+, and I need the preview. The file name is basically just a time stamp and therefore is not very readable.

Of course, my own script is not listed in either "recommended applications" or "other applications". (I think, if I built someone else's application from sources without installing it system-wide, the effect would be the same.)

How do I open a file with an application that doesn't appear in that list?

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a custom program to the list of  `All applications` in the part `Open with other application`, add a file yourapp.desktop in folder `~/.local/share/applications`
with content :

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=path_to_your_icon
Name[en_US]=yourapp
Exec=path_to_your_executable %F
Hidden=false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But in my case %U (one or more URLs) should be %F (one or multiple files)  https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

Comment: You are right.  I will correct it in my answer.  %U causes errors when you drag and drop one or more files on the icon.